# Champion Island; Where are the three pieces of driftwood that the Kijimuna asks you to find?

Tags: google-doodles

By the ocean, where the Marathon event is on Champion Island, is a Kijimuna that works in a studio producing wooden sculptures. She asks you to retrieve three pieces of driftwood that have washed up on the beach so that she may start a new sculpture. She would do it herself, but her poor knees are killing her.

Two of these pieces are very obviously placed on the beach itself directly outside of her studio. But where is the third one?

[image: kijimuna_studio]
[image: kimimuna_request]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need access to the "secret beach" past the tree on the right.

To get access to the secret beach, you need to get the friends a snack.

The snack is a melon bread from the bakery in Tanooki City.